# Implementing a binary search tree using std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, binary-search-tree

I have implemented a binary search tree with 2 operations to begin with. I have tried to implement it using the best practices I could think of. Overall, I am happy with the implementation. But, I want someone else's opinion about what they think about the design or any bad practice I have used.

I wanted to get rid of getLeftRef() and getRightRef() functions in Node class but they are being used in insert_ and delete_ function as parameters for the recursive call. Because in the insert_ and delete_ function we are reseating the unique_ptr, I passed it by reference and according to isocpp guidelines, it is ok to pass by unique_ptr reference if it is being used to reseat the unique_ptr. It would be great to have someone's review of this bit.

P.S. I am using C++11 so I cannot use make_unique instead of using new to allocate unique_ptr.

```
//
//  BST.hpp
//  PracticeC++
//

#ifndef BST_hpp
#define BST_hpp

#include <memory>

// Binary Search Tree class
class BST
{
private:
    // Binary Search Tree node
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node(int val, Node* p) : data(val), parent(p), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}

        bool isLeftChild() { return parent->left.get() == this; }
        bool isRightChild() { return parent->right.get() == this; }
        Node* getLeft() { return left.get(); }
        Node* getRight() { return right.get(); }
        Node* getParent() { return parent; }
        std::unique_ptr<Node>& getLeftRef() { return left; }
        std::unique_ptr<Node>& getRightRef() { return right; }
        int getData() { return data; }

        std::unique_ptr<Node> extract()
        { return isLeftChild() ? std::move(parent->left) : std::move(parent->right); }

        std::unique_ptr<Node> extractLeft() { return std::move(left); }

        std::unique_ptr<Node> extractRight() { return std::move(right); }

        void setLeft(std::unique_ptr<Node> n)
        {
            if (!n)
                return;

            n->Reparent(this);
            left = std::move(n);
        }

        void setRight(std::unique_ptr<Node> n)
        {
            if (!n)
                return;

            n->Reparent(this);
            right = std::move(n);
        }

        void resetParent() { parent = nullptr; }
        void setData(int val) { data = val; }

    private:
        // member variables
        int data;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
        Node* parent;

        void Reparent(Node* newParent) { parent = newParent; }
    };

    void insert_(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root, int val, Node* parent);
    bool remove_(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root, int val, Node* parent);
    std::unique_ptr<Node> extractInOrderPredOrSucc(Node* node, bool isPred);

    Node* find(Node* n, int val);
    Node* findInOrderPredecessor(Node* node);
    Node* findInOrderSuccessor(Node* node);

    // Member variables
    std::unique_ptr<Node> root;
public:

    void insert(int val) { insert_(root, val, nullptr); }
    bool remove(int val) { return remove_(root, val, nullptr); }
};


#endif /* BST_hpp */
```

```
//
//  BST.cpp
//  PracticeC++
//
//

#include "BST.hpp"

BST::Node* BST::findInOrderPredecessor(BST::Node* node)
{
    if (!node || !node->getLeft())
        return nullptr;

    node = node->getLeft();

    while (node->getRight())
        node = node->getRight();

    return node;
}

BST::Node* BST::findInOrderSuccessor(BST::Node* node)
{
    if (!node)
        return nullptr;
    else if (!node->getRight())
        return node->getParent();

    node = node->getLeft();

    while (node->getRight())
        node = node->getRight();

    return node;
}

std::unique_ptr<BST::Node> BST::extractInOrderPredOrSucc(BST::Node* node, bool isPred)
{
    if (isPred)
    {
        Node* n = findInOrderPredecessor(node);
        if (!n)
            return nullptr;
        auto subtree = n->extract();
        subtree->getParent()->setRight(subtree->extractLeft());
        subtree->resetParent();
        return subtree;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* n = findInOrderSuccessor(node);
        if (!n)
            return nullptr;
        auto subtree = n->extract();
        subtree->getParent()->setLeft(subtree->extractRight());
        subtree->resetParent();
        return subtree;
    }
}

void BST::insert_(std::unique_ptr<Node>& node, int val, Node* parent)
{
    if (!node)
    {
        node = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(val, parent));
        return;
    }

    return (val <= node->getData()
            ? insert_(node->getLeftRef(), val, node.get())
            : insert_(node->getRightRef(), val, node.get()));
}

bool BST::remove_(std::unique_ptr<Node>& node, int val, Node* parent)
{
    if (!node)
        return false;

    if (val == node->getData())
    {
        if (!node->getLeft())
        {
            if (!node->getRight())
                node.reset();
            else
                node->setRight(node->extractRight());
        }
        else
        {
            if (!node->getRight())
                node->setLeft(node->extractLeft());
            else
            {
                // Both children exist, so replace with either in-order pred or succ
                auto predNode = extractInOrderPredOrSucc(node.get(), true);

                predNode->setLeft(node->extractLeft());
                predNode->setRight(node->extractRight());

                node->isLeftChild()
                ? node->getParent()->setLeft(std::move(predNode))
                : node->getParent()->setRight(std::move(predNode));
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    return (val < node->getData()
            ? remove_(node->getLeftRef(), val, node.get())
            : remove_(node->getRightRef(), val, node.get()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Observation

I normally don't see a `parent` pointer in a binary tree.
Because you have to keep and maintain this extra pointer your code is a lot more complicated then it needs to be.

---

The `Node` object is part of `BST` so you don't need need an interface to protect you from changes. Any changes in the BST or node are going to result in changes in the other.

As a result I would simplify the `Node` to be a simple structure and get rid of that confusing mess of accessor functions.

---

Personally I don't use smart pointers to build containers. The container is its own manager of memory abstracting that out is redundant. Though others would argue with me on that point and I do see their point.

---

Your code can only store `int`. Why did you make this limitation. A simple templatization will allow you to store any type that is comparable.

### Alternative

This is to show that you made the code twice as long by simply adding the parent member to the class.

```
template<typename T>
class BST
{
    struct Node
    {
        Node*     left;
        Node*     right;
        T         value;
    };
    Node* root = nullptr;

    // This function assumes node is not null.
    // So check before you call.
    Node* findLeftMostNode(Node* node) {
        return node->left == nullptr ? node: findLeftMostNode(node->left);
    }

    Node* insertNode(Node* node, T consT& val) {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return new Node{nullptr, nullptr, val};
        }

        if (val < node->value) {
            node->left = insertNode(node->left, val);
        }
        else {
            node->right = insertNode(node->right, val);
        }
        return node;
    }
    Node* deleteNode(Node* node, T const& val)
    {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        if (val < node->val) {
            node->left = deleteNode(node->left, val);
        }
        else if (val > node->val) {
            node->right = deleteNode(node->right, val);
        }
        else {
            // The interesting part.
            Node* old = node;           // the node to delete;

            // If both children are null.
            // Simply delete the node and return nullptr
            // as the value to be used for this point.
            if (node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr) {
                node = nullptr;
            }
            // If either the left or right node is null
            // then we can use the other one as the replacement for
            // for node in the tree.
            else if (node->left == nullptr) {
                node = node->right;        // the node to return as replacement
            }
            else if (node->right == nullptr) {
                node = node->left;         // the node to return as replacement
            }
            else {
                // The shit just got real.
                // We can't delete the node (as we can return two pointers)
                old = nullptr;

                // This is the complicated part.
                // Remember that both the left and right are not nullptr.
                // So the leftmost sub-node of the right tree is the smallest
                // value in the right subtree. 
                // If we move this value to here then the right sub-tree can
                // still be on the right of this node.
                Node* leftMost = findLeftMostNode(node->right);
                // Don't need to re-shape the tree simply move the value.
                node->val   = leftMost->val;

                // We have moved the value.
                // But now we have to delete the value we just moved from the
                // right sub-tree. Luckily we have a function for that.
                node->right = deleteNode(node->right, leftMost->val);
            }
            delete old;
        }
        return node;
    }

    public:
        ~BST()
        {
            Node* bottomLeft = root == nullptr ? nullptr : findLeftMostNode(root);

            while (root) {
                Node* old = root;
                root = root->left;
                bottomLeft->left = old->right;
                bottomLeft = findLeftMostNode(bottomLeft);
                delete old;
            }
        }
        // Deletet the copy operator
        BST(BST const&)           = delete;
        BST& operator(BST const&) = delete;

        // Simple interface.
        void insertNode(T const& val) {root = insertNode(root, val);}
        void deleteNode(T const& val) {root = deleteNode(root, val);}
}
```